# "Figure" as name of listings in listoflistings with minted and newfloat

Tags: listings, minted, classicthesis

The following MWE gives me a List of Listings with "Figure" as name of listings.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}    
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}
\listoflistings
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{sql}
Test
\end{minted}
\caption{My Listing}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If I remove the `newfloat` option from minted, the "Figure"-String disappears. However, the desired behaviour would be to include something like "Listing" in front of every entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load `minted` before `classicthesis`, otherwise you get a

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
(name{figure.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

warning, with incorrect hyperlinks.

Then you can make `\l@listing` the same as `\l@figure`, which is what `newfloat` does anyway, but after `classicthesis` has modified the standard meaning of `\l@figure`. You can use a hook, usually empty, for locally changing `\figurename` to “Listing” and, possibly, for changing some of the indentation parameters.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\makeatletter
\let\l@listing\l@figure
\def\newfloat@listoflisting@hook{\let\figurename\listingname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoflistings

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{sql}
Test
\end{minted}
\caption{My Listing}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `babel` it seems that some timing problems arise. Here's a different workaround, including the change to the labels.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\listlistingname}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}%
  \renewcommand{\listingname}{Listing}%
}

\makeatletter
\let\l@listing\l@figure
\patchcmd{\l@listing}{\cftfigpresnum}{\cftlistingpresnum}{}{}
\newcommand\cftlistingpresnum{\listingname~}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoflistings

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{sql}
Test
\end{minted}
\caption{My Listing}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this stops working after including `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. Loading babel with the `ngerman` option changes the string back to the german word for figure ("Abbildung").

Comment: @StefanBraun Fixed

Comment: @StefanBraun Would you provide the words in place of `???`?

Comment: I chose "Quellcodeverzeichnis" as title, while the designator in front of every item stays as "Listing". I've used the english word "Listing" throughout my thesis for referencing source code samples ... I believe that's kind of standard in (german) technical literature. The commands are `\renewcommand{\listlistingname}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}` and `\renewcommand{\listingname}{Listing}`.

Answer (score 1):

minted loads the `newfloat`-Package if the identical option is applied. `newfloat` uses the `\listoffigure` command for new lists. Looks like this is a bit buggy - but I'm not sure who to blame: me, newfloat, minted or classicthesis.

In order to fix the list of listings I had to overwrite the `\cftfigpresnum` command.

```
\PrepareListOf{listing}{\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Listing~}}
```

---

Source:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/newfloat.pdf, page 5